# Make auto-generated command and how to bypass it?

Tags: makefile

The following file executes `make main`, and  command `g++ -c -o hhh.mk.o hhh.mk.cc` will be automatically generated. Why is this and how can I disable it?

Makefile

```
pre:
    sh touch.sh

-include hhh.mk

%.cc:
    echo $*

main: pre test.cc
    echo main
```

```
# touch.sh
touch hhh.mk
```

Some variables are saved in hhh.mk, which is caused by the fact that the file is not created. And hhh.mk is created by the script during the make.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand the intent of the makefile shown.  Please [edit] your question to show the contents of `hhh.mk` as well.

Comment: Important details reside in file `hhh.mk`, which you have not presented.  Please update the question to provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reminder, there are some variables saved in hhh.mk, due to my mistake, the file hhh.mk was not created in the test. It returned to normal after creation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU make knows how to build things from internal rules, including recursive invocations of these rules.  If you run `make -d` you'll see what it's doing, which is something like this:

```
 Considering target file 'hhh.mk'.
  File 'hhh.mk' does not exist.
  Looking for an implicit rule for 'hhh.mk'.
    ...
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'hhh.mk'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'hhh.mk.cc'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'hhh.mk.cc'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'hhh.mk'.
  Found an implicit rule for 'hhh.mk'.
   Considering target file 'hhh.mk.o'.
   File 'hhh.mk.o' does not exist.
   Considering target file 'hhh.mk.cc'.
    File 'hhh.mk.cc' does not exist.
    Finished prerequisites of target file 'hhh.mk.cc'.
   Must remake target 'hhh.mk.cc'.
echo hhh.mk
```

There are various ways to address this.  One simple way is:

```
MAKEFLAGS += -r
```

which will remove all of the default rules.  Another way is to create an explicit rule for building the included makefile:

```
hhh.mk: ; touch $@
```

Since it's explicit, make won't look for implicit rules to build it.

The solution that's best can't be provided without knowing more about your requirements.